# HTML meta tag for Windows Phone “website pin to start”

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, favicon

I'm developing website and I would like to know if it's possible to set shortcut icon for website (when you pin website to start screen on Windows phone mobile IE), just like on apple (apple touch icons).

I found this, but it doesn't work :(

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="windows_phone_icon.png">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#1B262B">
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Phone now supports the msapplication meta tags, as well as browserconfig.xml and RSS feed. If you did the work for IE10 or 11, it will now work on Windows Phone as well.

The code you suggested should do the trick with the latest Windows Phone update.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there isn't an option as good as you typed.

I already saw many sites using a clever hack to accomplish this.

You need to provide to the user some way to know the site can be pinned.

The user needs to trigger an action to show what you want in the tile an after that he needs to invoke the `...` and pin the site.

[Here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/19/creating-a-custom-tile-to-link-to-your-website.aspx) you can see a more elaborated post in Windows Phone Blog.

Comment: yeah this is a pretty sad thing for now. I have no clue why they did not support the Live Tile support build into the desktop experience. You can check out more on how to set that up on http://buildmypinnedsite.com

Comment: @ChrisLove Sorry but I think you made a mistake. this site is specific to Windows 8/8.1, the OP is asking about Windows Phone specifically. But thanks to share this site ;)

Comment: nope I did not, I stated that is how it should work, not how they implemented it. Instead they just give us a crappy Screen shot instead of honoring the live tile meta tags like the desktop does in IE 11/10. Hopefully soon!

Comment: Hey @ChrisLove. I think maybe you link can be helpful now a days. They just announce at Build 2014 some improvements and I think the tiles in Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 (expected for Q2 2014) will be the same.

Comment: :> I know, I cant wait for that to propogate to end users over the summer :D

Answer (score 0):

You might just be missing the self closing part in your tags:

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="windows_phone_icon.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#1B262B" />
```